# Fail to check the second character in argv[] in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, comparison, argv

I would like to check the arguments in `argv[]`, but it fails to check the second character.
For example,

I can do that:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  if (*argv[1] == "A")
    printf("Hello: %s\n", argv[1]);
}
```

However, I can't check `argv[1]` when I change "A" to "AB" like this:

```
if (*argv[1] == "AB")
  printf("Hello: %s\n", argv[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Strings are compared with `strcmp()` in C, almost never with `==`:

```
if(strcmp(argv[1], "AB") == 0)
  printf("the second argument is AB\n");
```

Note that 0 is returned when the compared strings are equal.

Answer (score 1):

On this line:

```
if (*argv[1] == "AB")
```

you're comparing a `char` to `char*`. These are different types. Also, even if the first operand was `char*` you should still not use `==` to compare strings since it merely compares the pointer values. Use [`strncmp()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/strncmp.html) instead

```
if (strncmp("AB", argv[1], 2) == 0)
```

This condition is true if two first characters of `argv[1]` are `"AB"`, e.g. if `argv[1]` is `"ABC"`. If you want to check that `argv[1]` is exactly `"AB"` use [`strcmp()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/strcmp.html) like this

```
if (strcmp("AB", argv[1]) == 0)
```

Note that it is fine to use `==` to compare single characters:

```
if (argv[1][0] == 'A')
```

Also, before you assume `argv[1]` is valid you should check `argc` to ensure you have actually  been given an argument.

Answer (score 0):

`*argv[1]` is a `char`. you should not compare it to string (`char*`). If you want you check if it's A, do `if (*argv[1]=='A')` If you want to check the whole argument, do it like `strcmp(argv[1],"AB")`

Answer (score 0):

You should stop comparing pointers and characters, this isn't healthy.

You can do `*argv[1]=='A'`. And when it comes two two characters, you should use `strncmp`.